# Proving the Product of Two Open Sets in ℝ is Open

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a proof which aims to show that for two open sets $A$ and $B$ in ℝ, the set $AB$, defined by $$AB = \{xy | x\in A, y \in B\}$$, is open. I'd like to ensure my proof is valid. Here's the proof I've formulated:

Let $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Given that both $A$ and $B$ are open, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subset A$ and $(y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon) \subset B$.

For the next part, I'm assuming $x > \epsilon > 0$ and $y > \epsilon > 0$. I believe that if either $x$ or $y$ is negative, we can handle it in a similar way.

We know that $(x-\epsilon)(y-\epsilon) < xy < (x+\epsilon)(y+\epsilon)$, which gives us $xy - \epsilon y - \epsilon x + \epsilon^2 < xy < xy + \epsilon y + \epsilon x + \epsilon^2$.

Since $(xy + \epsilon y + \epsilon x + \epsilon^2) - xy = (x+y + \epsilon)\epsilon > (x+y - \epsilon)\epsilon = xy - (xy - \epsilon y - \epsilon x + \epsilon^2)$, if we pick $\delta =(x+y - \epsilon)\epsilon$, then $D(xy, \delta) \subset AB$ where $D(xy, \delta) = \{z \in ℝ| d(xy, z) < \delta\}$.

I would appreciate it if anyone could provide some insights or corrections. Thanks!

Comment: It might be good to show your steps going from the inequality after "which gives us" and your claim that your defined $\delta$ satifies your final containment statement. Also you do not define $D(xy,\delta)$ [I assume you mean a ball around point $xy$ ?]

Comment: You must also take care of the case $xy=0.$

Comment: $$AB=\bigcup_{x\in A}xB$$ It's enough to show that $xB$ is open $\forall x\in A$

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks! Im aware of the proof. I just had this idea and would like to make sure it's right

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah yes. Thank you. Do you think the case where $x>0$ and$ y>0$ is valid? If so then I think the case where $xy=0$ is similar right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh if $x=0$ and $B\ne\varnothing,$ $xB$ is not open.

Comment: WinnieXi What you wrote is valid for the case $xy\ne0$ (split in 4 subcases), but the case $xy=0$ remains to be written. Actually, if $x\ne0$ then $xy\in xB\subset AB$ solves the question more rapidly, and similarly if $y\ne0$ $xy\in Ay\subset AB,$ so there only remains to treat the case $x=y=0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Correct. I was aware of this fact. Multiplication by a non zero vector induces a homeomorphism.

Comment: (by a non zero *scalar*, but the problem is precisely the opposite case: multiplication by the scalar $0$). So, you were aware that your comment above was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of  disjoint open intervals, it would be enough to prove the proposition for the case when A and B are of the form $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ respectively. But then for any $xy\in AB$ (where $x\in A,y\in B$) we have a neighbourhood $(x(y-\epsilon),x(y+\epsilon))$ contained in $AB$ for small enough $\epsilon >0$. So $xy$ is an interior point and the result follows.

PS. We have to keep in mind the signs of $a,b,c,d$ because minus sign can flip the resultant interval or neighbourhood.